# Block :hover on link for iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, css, ipad

I have a page which has sublinks having CSS as;

```
#leftNav .searchBySub {...} 
#leftNav a.searchBySub:hover {...} 
#leftNav .searchBySubClicked {...}
```

Now my question is on the iPad, the :hover styles get applied....So is there any way by which I can block them on the iPad

i.e. to say the iPad should see the CSS as;

```
#leftNav .searchBySub {...} 
#leftNav .searchBySubClicked {...}
```

I cannot just delete the :hover from the CSS, because the same CSS is used on both the desktop and the iPad.

I have already tried most of the basic things like

```
a[i].ontouchstart=function(e){  
e.stopPropagation();                                                  
e.preventDefault();                  
return false;
}
```

Comment: check for mobile OS and include a different stylesheet accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [***`Phil`***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185672/phil) said, ***"Check for mobile OS and include a different stylesheet accordingly."***

You can apply different *stylesheet* for different *browsers*.